# Unable to install latest spartacus 6 version

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to install Spartacus 5 or Spartacus 6 with storefront library as per [the documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/cfcf687ce2544bba9799aa6c8314ecd0/5de67850bd8d487181fef9c9ba59a31d.html) but getting error

```
Unable to fetch package information for '@spartacus/schematics@6.2.0': No matching version found for @spartacus/schematics@6.2.0.
```

On checking [npmjs website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@spartacus/schematics?activeTab=versions) I found out that the latest version released is 4.3.8. But when checking the [github tag](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tags) I see Spartacus 5.0.0 and 6.0.0. I am unable to understand which is the latest stable version available to consume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spartacus 5.0 onwards is shipped using RBSC.
Follow this url to install Spartacus

[Composable storefront](https://%20https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/cfcf687ce2544bba9799aa6c8314ecd0/5de67850bd8d487181fef9c9ba59a31d.html?locale=en-US)